# Which tag should we use if there exist two?

Tags: discussion

I am confused to know about the existed tags to select one in Magento stack exchange. Earlier we have some tags for the same purpose with two different names. Example,

1. [magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/tags/magento2/info)
2. [magento-2.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/tags/magento-2.0/info)

Answer (score 3):

These tags are not for the same purpose.

[magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2) means the question applies for all magento 2 versions
[magento-2.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-2.0) means the question applies for magento 2.0

Comment: it applies to all `Magento 2.0.x` versions

Comment: @marius, Okay sir, Thank you. But so many tags are there available in our Magento stack exchange, But here I gave this as an example.